# What is the computational cost of using complex numbers in contrast to real numbers in matrix operations, e.g. $LU$ or $LDL^T$ factorizations?

Tags: complexity, matrix-factorization, complex-arithmetic

I am curious about how much one loses in terms of computational cost when complex numbers are used instead of real numbers?

I guess the number of floating-point operations and memory doubles, but I am not sure if the wall time doubles necessarily. I am especially asking this for matrix factorizations, $LU$, or $LDL^T$ factorizations of complex symmetric (non-Hermitian) vs real-symmetric matrices. I am not sure if the answer changes based on using sparse or dense storage, but I'd appreciate if you comment on both situations. Obviously symmetric factorization cost should not change, but numerical factorizations should have a performance penalty.

Comment: Please supply some context for your Question.  Are there particular libraries or particular matrix operations involved?  The body of the Question should be as self-contained as possible, not relying on the title to pose the essential problem.

Comment: This is not worth an answer by itself, but it's worth pointing out: The multiplication of two complex numbers is four, not two, times more expensive than the multiplication of two real numbers.